# iTunesConnect (Testflight) prerelease testing is over. The app goes to App Store. Can it have the same version number as beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I mean: if beta say v2.2.4 build 1234 proves to be good, and will make its way to the App Store (this means the final release version will be the same (v2.2.4 build 1234). Will beta testers be able to "update" to the App Store version (which has the same version/build no.) to avoid their app become unusable after 30 days (when testflight beta validity ends)?

Or, is it even wise to use the same version/build number used in the last successful beta on the production version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: **YES**

It's perfectly fine to use the same beta build for production version. We do that all the time. Version number won't be an issue, in fact it is recommended.

The users will be able to download/update to App store version by downloading from `App Store` and can even go back to the beta build by again downloading it from `Testflight`.

Comment: The 2nd part of your answer is wrong- after the 60 day limit, users will not be able to go back to the beta build and download it again.  If the same version that was in the beta eventually was released in the app store, it will no longer be available in the beta the *moment* it is released in the app store, thus terminating the beta.