# Apple - how to persists data in TestFlight to production for my testers?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, testflight, persistent-storage

I asked this in the Apple forum however there have been no replies.

I use SQLite database in my app.  The data that is in my testers local db on the device.  How do I get that data for my testers into their production version of the app after they download it from the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK after publishing in App Store, Testflight users will be able to download app form store. It should work as regular update.

Comment: I think you may be missing my point.  The local database of the app will get destroyed as its in a sandbox of the device set up for TestFlight;  when the production version is downloaded does it not get its own new sandbox in which the database used in TestFlight will not be there?

Comment: No, Testflight apps don't have separate/own sandbox. It'll be treated as regular update (like from one version to another, both from App Store) so all your data will persist. Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655508/will-testflight-prerelease-beta-app-version-update-existing-app-store-version-o